# How do I compare a value across 2 arrays of objects with different property names?

Tags: javascript

**Issue**:
I am working with two arrays of objects containing some product data. They contain *some* of the same data (not all), **but the property names are not shared between the two**. Below is some sample data:

```
var productsOne = [
  { item: '1234', price: '2.00', quantity: '2' },
  { item: '5678', price: '7.19', quantity: '1' },
  { item: '2432', price: '3.59', quantity: '10' }
]

var productsTwo = [
  { itemNo: '2432', msrp: '3.59', inCart: '10' },
  { itemNo: '1234', msrp: '2.00', inCart: '2' },
  { itemNo: '5678', msrp: '7.19', inCart: '1' }
]
```

I need to compare values between these two variables. (For instance, checking if the value of `item` in any `productsOne` object equals the value of `itemNo` in any `productsTwo` object.)

**What I've tried**:

I know I need to use the map() method or something similar, so I started with this:

```
var itemNos = Array.prototype.map.call(productsTwo, function(obj) {
  return obj.itemNo;
});

productsOne.map(function(obj) {
  if (obj.item === itemNos) {
    // do something
  }
});
```

But I'm struggling working with map(), specifically checking for a given value stored in different property names. Is this the approach I should be taking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for:

> checking if the value of item in any productsOne object equals the
>   value of itemNo in any productsTwo object.

```
productsOne.forEach((o) => {
  if(productsTwo.some((o2) => o.item === o2.itemNo)) {
    // `itemNo` value identical to `item` value found, do something
  }
})
```

Or using nested `forEach`s:

```
productsOne.forEach((o) => {
  productsTwo.forEach((o2) => {
    if(o.item === o2.itemNo) {
    // `itemNo` value identical to `item` value found, do something
    console.log('o.item '+o.item+' is equal to '+o2.itemNo)
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of `itemNo` from `productsTwo` and then filter out objects from `productsOne` that have an `item` value in that set.

If you just want a boolean for "do some items in `productsOne` have an `item` value that is equal to any of the `itemNo` values in `productsTwo`", you can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (along with the set of extracted values).

```js
var productsOne = [
  { item: '1234', price: '2.00', quantity: '2' },
  { item: '5678', price: '7.19', quantity: '1' },
  { item: '2432', price: '3.59', quantity: '10' },
  { item: 'hello', price: '3.59', quantity: '10' }
];

var productsTwo = [
  { itemNo: '2432', msrp: '3.59', inCart: '10' },
  { itemNo: '1234', msrp: '2.00', inCart: '2' },
  { itemNo: '5678', msrp: '7.19', inCart: '1' }
];

var itemNos = new Set(productsTwo.map(p => p.itemNo));
console.log(Array.from(itemNos));

var common = productsOne.filter(p => itemNos.has(p.item));
console.log(common);

console.log(productsOne.some(p => itemNos.has(p.item)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
var productsOne = [
  { item: '1234', price: '2.00', quantity: '2' },
  { item: '5678', price: '7.19', quantity: '1' },
  { item: '2432', price: '3.59', quantity: '10' }
]

var productsTwo = [
  { itemNo: '2432', msrp: '3.59', inCart: '10' },
  { itemNo: '1234', msrp: '2.00', inCart: '2' },
  { itemNo: '5678', msrp: '7.19', inCart: '1' }
]

var matchedItems = productsOne.map(o1 => productsTwo.some(o2 => o1.item === o2.itemNo));
```